# Rails and capistrano deployment: bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

I want to push a Rails4 application with capistrano3.
But when I try, I get these errors:

```
INFO [c7c799a8] Running /containers/30054/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.0.0-p598 do bundle install --path /containers/30054/sites/myapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as user@MYSERVER
DEBUG [c7c799a8] Command: cd /containers/30054/sites/myapp/releases/20150330171635 && ( RVM_BIN_PATH=/containers/30054/.rvm/bin /containers/30054/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.0.0-p598 do bundle install --path /containers/30054/sites/myapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    You have deleted from the Gemfile:
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    * capistrano (~> 3.3.0)
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    * capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1.2)
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    * capistrano-rails (~> 1.1)
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    * capistrano-rvm
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    * capistrano3-puma
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    * mysql2 (~> 0.3.11)
DEBUG [c7c799a8]    * puma
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@MYSERVER: bundle exit status: 16
bundle stdout: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* capistrano (~> 3.3.0)
* capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1.2)
* capistrano-rails (~> 1.1)
* capistrano-rvm
* capistrano3-puma
* mysql2 (~> 0.3.11)
* puma
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 16
bundle stdout: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* capistrano (~> 3.3.0)
* capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1.2)
* capistrano-rails (~> 1.1)
* capistrano-rvm
* capistrano3-puma
* mysql2 (~> 0.3.11)
* puma
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as user@MYSERVER: bundle exit status: 16
bundle stdout: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* capistrano (~> 3.3.0)
* capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1.2)
* capistrano-rails (~> 1.1)
* capistrano-rvm
* capistrano3-puma
* mysql2 (~> 0.3.11)
* puma
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

Inside my deploy.rb I don't have specific tasks and my SCM does include the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you changed Gemfile, but didn't run bundle install on local machine.
So your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are out of sync.

Run bundle install on local machine to update Gemfile.lock and then commit and push changes.

Comment: I forgot to mention this: I've already tried and both are perfectly versioned/pushed.

Comment: If I were you, I'd compare Gemfile.lock on the server with local Gemfile.lock. Probably it is some capistrano/git issue.

Comment: There are no differencies between the Gemfile.lock on the server and the local machine. I'm searching on google and I can't find anything useful.